# How do I encode mp4 files with H.264 (or x264) codec in AVIDemux?

Tags: macos, mp4, h.264, encoding

I am trying to get AVIDemux set up with the X264 codec using [this](http://shiftpop.blogspot.com/2008/09/compiling-x264-with-mp4-support-on-os-x.html) tutorial. The following is what goes down when I get to the `./configure --enable-mp4-output` command

```
Thomas-Phillipss-MacBook:x264 tomdabomb2u$ sudo ./configure --enable-mp4-output
Password:
Unknown option --enable-mp4-output, ignored
Found no assembler
Minimum version is yasm-0.6.2
If you really want to compile without asm, configure with --disable-asm.
```

So I tried it.

```
Thomas-Phillipss-MacBook:x264 tomdabomb2u$ sudo ./configure --enable-mp4-output --disable-asm
Unknown option --enable-mp4-output, ignored
Warning: gpac is too old, update to 2007-06-21 UTC or later
Platform:   X86_64
System:     MACOSX
asm:        no
avs:        no
lavf:       no
ffms:       no
gpac:       no
pthread:    yes
filters:    crop select_every
debug:      no
gprof:      no
PIC:        no
shared:     no
visualize:  no
bit depth:  8

You can run 'make' or 'make fprofiled' now.
```

I issued `make`, and then `Thomas-Phillipss-MacBook:x264 tomdabomb2u$ ./x264 -v -q 20 -o foreman.mp4 foreman_part_qcif.yuv 176x144`. And as expected, the results are:

```
x264 [error]: not compiled with MP4 output support
```

So I'm stuck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

That's a pretty old tutorial. Try [this one](http://www.avidemux.org/admWiki/doku.php?id=build:compiling_x264) (linked from the official Avidemux site).

Comment: The tutorial you've linked to doesn't mention this issue - are you expecting it to fix something specifically or is it just a guess?

Answer (score 0):

Fast solution:

1. If you have x264, don't worry about un-install. Stay with it.
2. Check your assembler yasm verison.
3. Install gpac --> from svn.code.sf.net and compile it.
4. Copy gpac/inlucde/gapc/ into x264
5. inside x264 and configure as follow

   ```
   ./configure --extra-ldflags=-L/home/../gpac/bin/gcc --enable-mp4 --enable-shared --enable-debug --enable-PIC
   ```
6. You get the list in the configure x264 and you can easily find that your MP4 from 'no' changed to 'gpac'
7. Enter `make`
8. Enter `make install`
9. Write x264 command as `x264 big_buck_bunny.y4m -o big_buck_bunny.mp4` to test it. Now you have mp4 video. In this process it's not necessary to convert raw video to h264 and then in a second step with another tool to mp4.

Answer (score 0):

Installed the latest version at http://nasm.us
in /usr/local/bin/nasm, ran ./configure again, fixed.